# What's the meaning of the bytes between `FilePathListLength` and `Description` in a `Boot####` EFI variable?

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, efi

I was playing around with the EFI variables in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` and stumbled upon something I don't understand while trying to parse their contents. According [to the latest spec](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202.8B%20May%202020.pdf) of the EFI document (Sec. 3.3 *Globally defined variables*), each `Boot####` variable contains a `struct` describing an `EFI_LOAD_OPTION` (Sec. 3.1.3 *Load Options*). The struct (supposedly) is

```cpp
struct efi_device_path_protocol {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t stype;
    uint8_t length[2];
}

struct efi_load_option {
    uint36_t                 attributes;
    uint16_t                 file_path_list_length;
    char16_t                 description[];
    efi_device_path_protocol file_path_list[];
    uint8_t                  optional_data[];
}
```

An `hexdump` of one random `Boot####` variable on my system yields

```
00000000  07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  0d 00 55 00 45 00 46 00  |..........U.E.F.|
00000010  49 00 3a 00 52 00 65 00  6d 00 6f 00 76 00 61 00  |I.:.R.e.m.o.v.a.|
00000020  62 00 6c 00 65 00 20 00  44 00 65 00 76 00 69 00  |b.l.e. .D.e.v.i.|
00000030  63 00 65 00 00 00 05 01  09 00 82 00 00 00 00 7f  |c.e.............|
00000040  ff 04 00                                          |...|
00000043
```

and I was expecting

- the first 4 bytes to be the attributes: this is OK, a value of 7 in this case is expected;
- the next 2 bytes to be an integer, telling me the length in bytes of the field `field_path_list`: that field is optional, but here it says that it's 1 byte long. But the `struct` that is supposedly there is at a minimum 4 bytes long. What?
- the next string of bytes (until a null character) are `char16_t` characters, encoding the description of this boot option. But the first `char16_t` after the `field_path_list_length` **is** a null character, so there is no description?

But there **is** a description: `UEFI:Removable Device`. But this is true only if I skip the 4 bytes between `field_path_list_length` and what looks like the actual start of the `description[]`.

Is my firmware non-conformant? Am I missing something? What are those 4 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

In /sys/firmware/efi/efivars, the first four bytes are attributes [**for the variable itself**](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/firmware/efivars.c?id=5d9db883761ad1bc2245fd3018715549b974203d), corresponding to the `Attributes` parameter that is returned by GetVariable() (see section  *8.2 Variable Services* for the flag definitions). The actual `Data` of the variable starts 4 bytes later.

Note that you wouldn't normally have 0x7 as efi_load_option.attributes, as there is no definition for bit 0x4 in section 3.1.3.

(Also note that *struct efi_device_path_protocol* only defines the header of each path item – there will be additional fields depending on the type & subtype, so *file_path_list[]* is not exactly like a regular C array, and the entire structure is not exactly like a regular C struct.)

In other words, you're looking at:

```
struct {
    uint32_t Attributes = 0x00000007, /* NON_VOLATILE | BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS | RUNTIME_ACCESS */
    Data[] = (struct efi_load_option) {
        uint32_t attributes = 0x00000001, /* ACTIVE */
        uint16_t file_path_list_length = 0x000d, /* 13 */
        char16_t description[] = L"UEFI:Removable Device",
        file_path_list[] = {
            {
                uint8_t type = 0x05, /* BIOSBootDevice - table 44 */
                uint8_t subtype = 0x01, /* BiosBootDevice */
                uint16_t length = 0x0009, /* 4 (header) + 5 (data) */
                /* table 101 */
                uint16_t device_type = 0x0082, /* unknown reserved value */
                uint16_t status_flag = 0x0000,
                char description_string[] = "",
            },
            {
                uint8_t type = 0x7f, /* EndOfDevicePath - table 44 */
                uint8_t subtype = 0xff, /* EndEntireDevicePath - table 45 */
                uint16_t length = 0x0004, /* 4 (header) + 0 (data) */
                /* no data */
            },
        },
        uint8_t optional_data[] = {},
    }
}
```